# Wildfly Postgres Connection Failed

Tags: postgresql, wildfly

I've tried to add Postgres as datasource in Wildfly but keep on getting the JDBC connection error as follow :

> Failed to create JDBC connection.
>
> An internal error occurred. Details Unexpected HTTP response: 500
>
> Request {
>       "name" => "PostgresDS",
>       "enabled" => true,
>       "jndi-name" => "java:/PostgresDS",
>       "user-name" => "admin",
>       "password" => "123",
>       "pool-name" => "PostgresDS_Pool",
>       "use-ccm" => false,
>       "jta" => false,
>       "connection-url" => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgresdb",
>       "driver-class" => "org.postgresql.Driver",
>       "driver-name" => "postgresql-9.4.1208.jar",
>       "valid-connection-checker-class-name" => "org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker",
>       "background-validation" => true,
>       "exception-sorter-class-name" => "org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter",
>       "operation" => "add",
>       "address" => [
>           ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>           ("data-source" => "PostgresDS")
>       ] }
>
> Response
>
> Internal Server Error {
>       "outcome" => "failed",
>       "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0212: Duplicate resource [
>       (\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),
>       (\"data-source\" => \"PostgresDS\") ]",
>       "rolled-back" => true }

Comment: When does this error occur? It looks like something is trying to add the datasource twice.

Comment: Hi @JamesR.Perkins. Its happen when I tried to add a new Datasource. Weird because I just set up my Wildfly (fresh installation) and never register any datasource before. My steps : Configuration > Subsystems > Datasources > Non-XA > Add. Did I miss anything here?

Comment: It looks like then you're trying to add a data source that already exists. Try using a different name or modify the existing one.